# Can't receive updated extras from Pendingintent when calling the same activity next time

Tags: android

Basically i am trying to open an already active activity with new data. I have added Bundle with extras to Pendingintent from a Notification. But I am not able to get the updated values in activity.
Here is my code

```
    Intent in = new Intent(c, HomePageActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean("id", "1234");
        in.putExtras(bundle);

    in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    in.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, in,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And OnResume() in called MyActivity, But the id value is old one '1111'

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (getIntent().hasExtra("id")) {
        Log.e("id", getIntent().getStringExtra("id"));
    }
}
```

But it returns '1111'

Please give me a solution.

Comment: Why putboolean instead of putInt or putString ?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling getIntent().getExtras() again before trying to get the new value. That should update the values of the extras.

Answer (score 0):

Try using onNewIntent

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        if(intent.getExtras()!=null)
        {
          String id = intent.getExtras().getStringExtra("id");
            updateValues(id);
        }
    }
```